# Why am I getting a 404 error when i try to use php to send me an email on my website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to be emailed the email addresses of the people that sign up. I don't know much about php, but I would like to use the mail() method to send the emails to me. When someone signs up, a 404 error pops up, and it says, "This error is generated when there was no web page with the name you specified at the web site."

This is simply a landing page, and I don't know much about php, so I'm not exactly sure what to try.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
<h1>AmCompare is a New App that Helps You Save Time and Money!</h1>
<div id="container">
  <p id="welcome">
    <b>Hello!</b><br /><br />We hope you're having an awesome day. AmCompare is an app that can instantly compare the price of a product to similar products on Amazon. All it takes is a picture, and AmCompare will find you the best deal online to
    help you save money! By signing up below, you're showing interest in a product designed to help you save time and money.
        <br /><br />
        <b>Thanks so much,</b>
        <br /> The Entire AmCompare Team
      </p>
      <form style="border:1px solid #ccc" method="post">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>
        <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">
    Sign Up
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">&copy; AmCompare 2019</div>
    <script src="share.js"></script>

<br>
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  echo "Error; You need to submit the form.";
}
$email = $_POST['email'];
if(empty($email)) {
  echo "Email is mandatory.";
  exit;
}
$email_from = '$email \n';
$email_subject = "New Form Submission";
$email_body = "New email: $email \n".
$to = "jordanpattonsnowflake@gmail.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
?>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think this error has nothing to do with your PHP code, it might be the URL used in the HTML form (on the sign-up page) which is wrong. Can you please post your HTML code too? Thank you.

Comment: Your form's action="action_page.php". Does this page exist because that is the page called by your form.

Comment: A small note, is this line: `$email_body = "New email: $email \n".` supposed to end with a period, or did you forget a semicolon?